# Coproduct of projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In EGA II 5.5.6 it is said that the coproduct of two projective schemes is projective. I don't understand why this is true.

It is mentionned that it is a consequence of the definition of a projective morphism and of the Segre embedding. Let me remind you of those two thing

A morphism of schemes $f : X \to Y$ is projective if it factorizes through a closed immersion $i : X \to \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E})$ for a quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_Y$-module of finite type $\mathscr{E}$. This is not the "modern" definition but I imagine that if the result is true with this definition it is true with the more modern one.

The segre embedding says that for two quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathscr E_1$ and $\mathscr{E}_2$ over a scheme $Y$ there is a closed immersion $\mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_1) \times_Y \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_2) \to \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_1 \otimes_{\mathscr{O}_Y} \mathscr{E}_2)$. It is usually stated as $\mathbf{P}^n \times \mathbf{P}^m \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}^{mn + m + n}$.

I imagine that the idea is two say that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two projective schemes (who factorize through $\mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_1)$ and $\mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_2)$ respectively) there is a closed embedding
$$
X_1 \coprod X_2 \to \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_1) \times_Y \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{E}_2)
$$
in which case the result would indeed follow from the segre embedding. But I really don't see why that would be true.

Comment: I don't see a use of the Segre embedding. They refer to 4.3.6 which tells you how to embed the coproduct of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ and $\mathbb{P}(F)$ inside of $\mathbb{P}(E\oplus F)$. Doesn't that do it?

Comment: Oh i missread and thought they reffered to 4.3.2 which the segre embedding and which doesn't help. But you are absolutely right 4.3.6 does what we want. Thank you so much ! (I am ashamed)

Comment: Although now I ask myself, is it true that projective morphisms are stable by coproduct with the more "modern" definition of projective ?

Comment: What's the modern definition? The one you give is what Stacks uses, I think, and that's about as modern as it gets. Note that the definition in Hartshorne is more restrictive.

Comment: What I maybe incorrectly called the "modern" definition is the one that says that X is projective if it factors through $\mathbf{P}^n_Y$ for some $n$.

Comment: The reason I wonder about this is because in this note http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/Schemes_2009/Hansheng-notes.pdf he uses the result (first step of the proof) I ask about in my question for Hartshorne's definition of projective. But now i'm not sure that it works.

Comment: Well $\mathbf{P}^n_Y = \mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus(n+1)})$, right? So it seems like everything goes through.

Comment: Ah you are right ! I was thinking that $\mathbf{P}^n_Y = \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{O}_Y[X_1,...,X_n])$ but of course in fact it is $Proj(\mathscr{O}_Y[X_1,...,X_n]) = Proj(Sym_{\mathscr{O}_Y} \mathscr{O}_Y^{\oplus(n+1)}) = \mathbf{P}(\mathscr{O}_Y^{\oplus(n+1)})$ Thanks you so much for your help. If you want to indicate why I was wrong in an answer I will accept it.